# JSON is not showing value

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, struts2

I am using struts2 and and jquery to fetch value from server. Here execute() method is calling properly but in jsp  value is not shown.

Action class

```
 package example;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {

    private String name;
    private String welcomeMessage;

    @Override
    public String execute() {

        System.out.println("Inside Action name is " + getName());
        setWelcomeMessage("Welcome " + getName() + "!!");
        System.out.println(getWelcomeMessage());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getWelcomeMessage() {
        return welcomeMessage;
    }

    public void setWelcomeMessage(String welcomeMessage) {
        this.welcomeMessage = welcomeMessage;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
 <package name="example1" extends="json-default">
        <action name="test" class="example.HelloWorld">
            <result  type="json"></result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Jsp page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON EXAMPLE</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" id="introForm">
            <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
            <input name="name" id="name">
            <input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <div class="result"></div>
        <script>
            $("#button1").click(function() {

                var name1=$("#name").val();
                alert("name is "+name1);//showing entered name
                $.getJSON('test', { name: name1}, function(data) {
                    alert(data); // not calling
                    $('.result').html(data.welcomeMessage);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have included `jsonplugin-0.34.jar` in my lib folder.

Program is executing properly, not showing any error.
Here I am trying to fetch `welcomeMessage` from action in `<div class="result"></div>`.

Problem is it is not showing JSON value in jsp page.

Alert `alert(data);`  inside `$.getJSON('test', { name: name1}, function(data) {` is not calling.
Please see where is the problem.

Comment: Which version of Struts are you using?

Comment: I am using `Struts 2.3.4`

Comment: Then use `struts2-json-plugin` of that version.

Comment: This program is perfectly working by including `struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.jar'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine (except for the `<input>`s that are not (self)closed, and for the script in the body that should stay in the head inside a [`$( document ).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) snippet);

I guess you have simply been fooled by the download page of the S2 JSON plugin. That page is old and unmaintained, 0.32 and 0.34 are really old versions;

Always refer to the Maven repository for this:

> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin

and be sure to pick up the version matching the one of your struts2-core JAR.

Comment: I have included  `struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.jar`. Now this program is perfectly working.